What are good strategies to teach Prophet to interpolate data?
I have a few years worth of temperature data that is often sampled every ~20 minutes, but there are also gaps, could be many days of gaps, although more commonly an hour or two. I thought to use Prophet and ask it to interpolate the missing data.
Result is above. It recognizes the daily seasonality but is not really attempting to match daily variation. This is with
model = Prophet(daily_seasonality=False)  
model.add_seasonality(name='daily', period=1, fourier_order=20)  # Add custom daily seasonality

Are there some other parameters that I could tweak to encourage a better fit with existing data?
Thanks,

I think this comes down to the Prophet expectation of normalized data. I took a few hundred days, did some clever tricks to interpolate missing data, normalized them, and averaged them together and I could get a lovely spline fit through the average. I then FFT'd the spline fit and, lo-and-behold 5-10 coefficients of a Fourier was indeed just fine to fit that average function. Which reduces the interpolation problem to normalization of "seasonal" function with missing data... which comes down to interpolating the missing data which.. er...

I was able to simultaneously detrend the timeseries and interpolate the missing data by assuming a periodic function F(t) defined by 16 spline points over the course of just one day and then L2-minimizing difference against A(t)*F(t-T(t))+B(t) where A(t), T(t) and B(t) were splines with knots at midnight and noon each day. I used scipy PchipInterpolator rather than traditional cubic splines.

So I suppose this functional is similar to what Prophet minimizes [although it uses Fourier terms for F(t)] but I have more flexibility in defining a trend. Or the opposite, I'm not positing a trend in the A(t), B(t) at all.
